# Installing fglrx driver Ubuntu

Tags: radeon, fglrx, amd-graphics

I am installing the fglrx driver, as described in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI.
The problem is now that when I type the command

```
aticonfig --initial
```

, I get the following:

```
"aticonfig: No supported adapters detected",
```

and  then X is not loaded in Ubuntu.
My GPU is AMD Radeon HD 7600M Series.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same card and the closed-source drivers in ubuntu 13.10 doesn't work at all. No matter if you try the ones from ati website, the ones from ubuntu ppa, or the ones from xorg-edgers ppa...

For  now, the only one that works is the open-source driver. If you want to get them  improved there's a ppa with some fixes for them here:

https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers/

First, be sure any fglrx is removed from the system:

If you installed them trough a ppa:

```
sudo apt-get remove fglrx*
```

If you installed using the .run package from ati website, you'll have to run the ati-uninstaller manually (not sure where it is, but you can have a look in /usr/share/ati).

And then, add the ppa and install xserver-xorg-video-ati or xserver-xorg-video-all

```
sudo apt-add-repository  ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get  update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-all
```