# Any way there to get my amd to vga controller? for UBUNTU 18.04 lts

Tags: amd-graphics, vga

I have amd graphics card and I think it is not in use, have tried a lot but failed, and also I ruined my system. Help
[once click here for the picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Bmn.jpg)

Comment: I don't see there any solution for ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I got my system crashed again when I install driver ,when I install and reboot, it hangs saying changrs.pp link was shut down,

Comment: I am using bionic ubuntu 18.04 lts, and amd is still showing as display controller whereas intel show as vga  and `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` gives  `OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the radeon driver for the 8670 AMD graphics:

In 16.04 and above there is a default open source radeon driver:

[How to install the open-source "radeon" driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785788/how-to-install-the-open-source-radeon-driver)

On 14.04 there is fglrx binary driver available from AMD.

[Installing fglrx driver Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395954/installing-fglrx-driver-ubuntu)

Comment: I got my system crashed again when I install driver ,when I install and reboot, it hangs saying changrs.pp link was shut down,